# Wamp not recognizing a change in my code?

Tags: javascript, wamp

I'm working with Wamp, and i just added a console.log line.

```
console.log("message);
```

However, the message isn't being displayed in the console. After a bit of research, i found out that the source code of the page displayed on my browser ISN'T including the console.log line.

It seems like Wamp isn't recognizing the changes in my code all of a sudden.

I tried restarting it but still the same issue. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is javascript you are amending. Javascript is cached in the browser, so if you make a javascript change on the server it is sometimes necessary to tell your browser to refresh all its cache's.

You do this by loading the page you want to see and then pressing CTRL+F5 (both together) The browser will reload the page and all its resources, bringing up your amended javascript from the server in the process.